# WooCommerce new order - php (variable product)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

I created a custom checkout with a simple product - the question is:
I need to add a variable product to the order - because all purchases now are a simple product (id, quantity) ... can anyone help?

```
            $counter = 0;
            $u_meta = get_user_meta($user_ID);
            $post_id = "user_".$user_ID;
            $shipping_data = get_field('shiping_data', $post_id );
            $address = array(
              'first_name' => $u_meta['first_name'][0],
              'last_name'  => $u_meta['last_name'][0],
              'company'    => $u_meta['billing_company'][0],
              'email'      => $u_meta['billing_email'][0],
              'phone'      => $u_meta['billing_phone'][0],
              'address_1'  => $u_meta['billing_address_1'][0],
              'address_2'  => $u_meta['billing_address_2'][0],
              'city'       => $u_meta['billing_city'][0],
              'state'      => $u_meta['billing_state'][0],
              'postcode'   => $u_meta['billing_postcode'][0],
              'country'    => 'Israel'
            );
             $shipping = array(
              'first_name' => $shipping_data['shiping_name'],
              'last_name'  => $shipping_data['shiping_lastname'],
              'company'    => $shipping_data['company_name'],
              'email'      => $shipping_data['email_address'],
              'phone'      => $shipping_data['phone'],
              'address_1'  => $shipping_data['street_address'],
              'address_2'  => $shipping_data['billing_address_2'],
              'city'       => $shipping_data['city'],
              'state'      => $shipping_data['city'],
              'postcode'   => $shipping_data['zip_address'],
              'country'    => 'Israel'
            );
            // Now we create the order
            $order = wc_create_order();
            // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
            foreach($orders_id_l_v as $val){
                 $order->add_product( get_product($val[0]), $val[1]);
            }
            $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
            $order->set_address( $shipping, 'shipping' );
            $order->calculate_totals();
            $order_last_id = $order->get_order_number();
            update_post_meta($order_last_id, '_customer_user', get_current_user_id());
            $order->reduce_order_stock();
            $order->set_payment_method('PayMe');
            $order->payment_complete('PayMe ID:'.$payme_signature.', PayMe Selle ID:'.$payme_sale_id.',Payme transaction id:'.$payme_transaction_id);
            $order->add_order_note( 'Product Varible Name : '.$prod_full_name );
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();
```

Now the product name is variable, I write in the note ... but it shouldn’t be like that - thanks for the help!

Comment: if someone is looking for a solution, then it is simple: there is data in $ cart and inside the object there is variation_id the ego just needs to be substituted for id.